# invalid syntax when converting tflite into .cc buffer using xxd

Tags: python, python-3.x, embedded, jupyter, tflite

I have tflite model. When converting tflite model into 'C' buffer getting invalid syntax.

xxd -i model.tflite > minimal_data.cc.

Could some one help me whats wrong here?

Thanks

Tried in Jupyter, spyder and even google colab. all giving me same error

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us the exact error you are getting? It seems highly unlikely that `xxd` is giving you an error. What else are you doing?